# config in windows service

Tags: windows, service

for website emailing I was using :

```
string c = System.Web.Configuration.WebConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["CommonEmail"].ConnectionString;
```

in my windows service what should I change this configuration to read from service.exe.config?
 service.exe.config

```
<configuration>
<connectionStrings>
<add name="CommonEmail" connectionString="metadata=res:..
```

Comment: Why use `System.Web.Configuration` in a Windows Service? Why `Web`?

Comment: Try `System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["CommonEmail"]` instead.